# How to go back to the login screen when the computer locks? LightDM

Tags: login, lightdm, login-screen, lock-screen

I was wondering if there is a way for LightDM to return to the login screen instead of showing a the current user's lock screen without logging them out. It would be ideal if I do not need to apply the settings to every user. I tried looking into `[SeatDefault]` options for `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` but everything I found did not help me or was outdated. Thanks!